# os.path.exists() always returns false

Tags: python-3.x, os.path

I am trying to check if a file exits or not in the specified directory. If it is, then I would move the file to another directory. Here is my code

```
def move(pnin, pno):
    if (os.path.exists(pnin)):
        shutil.move(pnin, pno)
```

here is an example of pnin and pno

```
pnin='D:\\extracted\\extrimg_2016000055202500\\2016000055202500_65500000007006_11_6.png'
pno=D:\folder\discarded
```

I have a bit more than 8000 input directories. I copied this pnin from the output of `print(pnin)`.When I define pnin externally as in the example, the if statement works. But when I want to run 'move' function iteratively, if statement is never executed. What could be the problem and how can I solve this?
Here is how I call move function:

```
def clean_Data(inputDir, outDir):
    if (len(listf) > 1):
        for l in range(1,len(listf)):
            fname = hashmd5[m][l]    
            pathnamein = os.path.join(inputDir, fname)
            pathnamein = "%r"%pathnamein
            pathnameout = outfile
            move(pathnamein, pathnameout)
```

When I try below code it does not give any output. For loop şs working. When I use `print(pathnamein)` in the for loop it shows all the values of pathnamein.

```
def move(pnin, pno):
    os.path.exists(pnin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use backslash to escape backslashes in your `pno` string:

```
pno='D:\\folder\\discarded'
```

or use a raw string instead:

```
pno=r'D:\folder\discarded'
```

Otherwise `\f` would be considered a formfeed character.

Comment: I tried with pno=r'D:\folder\discarded'. Actually the path is different. but since it is too long I just wrote folder instead the whole path name. If statement never works when I use 'def move(pnin, pno):' in a for loop. When I specify 'pnin' in console to try the if statement it works.

Comment: I see. Can you update your question with the code of how you call `move` in a `for` loop?